# Is there any way that I can have a search bar hidden until a user scrolls up...similar to the messages app on an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, search, hidden

Basically, when a page loads, I want it to already be scrolled just a little bit so that a search bar at the top of the page is under the header. When a user scrolls up, they can then see it and use it.

I set the CSS like this:

```
.stickySearch{
    width:56% !important;
    position:fixed !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

The JS that I use is this:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st<=lastScrollTop){
        //scroll up
        if($(this).scrollTop()>235) $('#searchInput').removeClass('slideIn').addClass('stickySearch');
        else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').addClass('slideIn');
    }
    else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').removeClass('slideIn');
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

For some reason it isn't working...
Any ideas?

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it is. So if you wanted a different answer, it's important to ask the right question, after making sure you've read (and are following) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask while being aware that Stackoverflow is here to help you figure out why what you're already trying isn't working. It's not here to help you get started from scratch, that's your responsibility (google searching, SO searching, etc) and then when you think you have something that should work, but doesn't, that's the time to ask your question on stackoverflow.

Comment: CSS I have: `.stickySearch{
    width:56% !important;
    position:fixed !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}` this is the java script that I run upon page load: `var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st<=lastScrollTop){
        //scroll up
        if($(this).scrollTop()>235) $('#searchInput').removeClass('slideIn').addClass('stickySearch');
        else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').addClass('slideIn');
    }
    else $('#searchInput').removeClass('stickySearch').removeClass('slideIn');
    lastScrollTop = st;
});` ideas

Comment: Then mention your research efforts/results in your question, create a jsfiddle.net and properly describe your problem instead of writing a high level concept of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Please do not add any code or additional details via comments - edit your post: your question should contain all the details, even if some of those details come after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was just a bit out of order. Adding brackets to the if statements allowed me to quickly see the issue. I also changed where you were testing if the user was past the top of screen.

**JS**

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st > 235) {        
        if(st<=lastScrollTop){
            //scroll up
            $('#searchInput').removeClass('slideOut');
        } else {
            //Scroll down
            $('#searchInput').addClass('slideOut');
        }

    } else {
        //At top of page
        $('#searchInput').removeClass('slideOut');
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.stickySearch{
    width:56% !important;
    position:fixed !important;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    transition: height 100ms linear;
}

.slideOut {
    height: 0em;
}
```

Provided fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/op6p9xb7/1/

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything different than not having the code at all. I don't know of this makes a difference or not but this is for an app for a phone not a website. I need the component "searchInput" to be hidden under the header unless a user scrolls up.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if it is a html5 app. Did you look at the fiddle, noting the appropriate css along with it?

Comment: I did look at fiddle and added the css to my app but it didn't make a difference yet. Would it be easier to have the page already scrolled just a little bit?